# How re run the continumio/anaconda3 docker image?

Tags: docker, anaconda

I followed instructions on https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/anaconda3 and was able to get jupyter notebook running (also added the --allow-root to the command)

```
docker run -i -t -p 8888:8888 continuumio/anaconda3 /bin/bash -c "/opt/conda/bin/conda install jupyter -y --quiet && mkdir /opt/notebooks && /opt/conda/bin/jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --ip='*' --port=8888 --no-browser --allow-root"
```

But when trying to re-run the same container with command

```
docker start <CONTAINER_ID> && docker exec -d -t <CONTAINER_ID> /bin/bash -c "/opt/conda/bin/jupyter notebook --notebook-dir=/opt/notebooks --ip='*' --port=8888 --no-browser --allow-root"
```

The container works for a while and then dies.
Even if I only start notebook container, it automatically dies after sometime.

Has anyone else encountered the same problem with continumio anaconda image ?
How do I resolve it ?

Comment: It may be useful to specify container name if you are going to refer it later - instead of CONTAINER_ID. Just fyi in case you didnt know: `docker run ... --name foo ...` and later `docker start foo`

Comment: @grapes will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the log on stopped container it shows `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/notebooks/’: File exists`. The issue is with `docker start` it reruns the provided command: `/bin/bash -c "... && mkdir /opt/notebooks && ..."`, so it would fail at second attempt.

Use the `-p` option for `mkdir` so it wouldn't fail if the folder exists. Then for restarting it, just `docker start <container>`

Comment: Thanks @Siyu
This seems to solve the problem. 

But I'm still not clear on how docker start reruns the command used at the time of creation (the docker run command). Is it a default behavior ?

btw how did you inspect the stopped container 
Is there a docker command for that ?

Answer (score -1):

Run `docker container list -a` and find the exited container and start again using `docker start <CONTAINER_ID>`.

Open http://localhost:8888 in your browser.

Sometimes when I am commanding into container and trying to write file, I have experienced crashes.

Comment: I have tried re-running the containers multiple times but no luck